# How to extract dependencies from an Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I need to re-knit a long Rmarkdown document (about 3k lines.). But the author used some packages that I don't have. So I need to install them first.

Is there any way to save all or some of my efforts to manually check the whole document?

Comment: `purl()` will extract all the R chunks, and you could grep for packages there.

Comment: @baptiste Thanks! Please add it to the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: then you can also take a look at the packrat package; in particular, https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/blob/0e360b5c15d319b796a1d4fdc83a2c5ae7a67333/R/dependencies.R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`purl()` will extract all the R chunks, and you could `grep()` for packages there.